# Authentication Error while connecting VSCODE with Google Colab

Tags: ssh, google-colaboratory, vscode-remote

I tried to connect VS CODE with Google Colab cloud storage using the SSH key. For that, I took the following steps:

1. Ran the code of the highest voted answer of the following link in the Google Colab editor: [Is it possible to connect vscode (on a local machine) with Google Colab (the free service) runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508225/is-it-possible-to-connect-vscode-on-a-local-machine-with-google-colab-the-fre)
2. After getting the port number and password, using this tutorial: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh [Steps mentioned under "Getting Started" section], I typed **ssh {My email address}@0.tcp.ngrok.io:{Port Number}**.

The problem occurred when I typed the password; It gives me the following error:
[SSH Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVeko.png)

Now, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your first step, the creation of **ngrok** tunnel for **SSH** connection should generate something like this:

```sh
username: root
password: wtPUPjhjkhkjhkjhadsfhkj2LcycqC
ssh root@2.tcp.ngrok.io -p 10377
```

The outcome might vary depending on which Python script you use on **Colab** to evoke the **ngrok** service.

Go to **VS Code**, open the configuration file of the **Remote-SSH** extension. Add the following thing into the file:

```sh
Host Colab
    HostName 2.tcp.ngrok.io
    User root
    Port 10377
```

You may need to modify it according to the credential generated by **ngrok**.

Now following the steps below to connect yourself to the remote host via **VS Code**:

1. Go to VS Code's **Remote Explorer**.
2. Right click the entry **Colab** (you just created it in the configuration file)
3. Choose the way you prefer to connect your local machine to the host.
4. Click **Continue** in the first onscreen dialog window.
5. When you are prompted to enter password, use the one created by **ngrok**.

Then you're all set.